# How to get certain sum in horizontally and vertically in a multiarray

Tags: java, arrays, loops

This question is to print out a 2D array base on the input array(int[][] a), find all adjacent and continuous(horizontal and vertical) values that have the wanted sum(sumToFind is the parameter), and then create a new array(b) with the same dimension as a does, paste the original value from a if the value is included in the sumToFind, print out 0 in that place if it is not included.(I am not a native speaker, sorry for bad grammar =)
For example, if `sumToFind` is 20, then the horizontal sum method would find all horizontally continuous values in the input array that equal 20 and put them into a new output array, and values that aren’t in a horizontal sum equal to 20 would be set to zero in the output array. Similarly, vertical sums will be found the same way except their sums will be vertical.

Now I am having trouble of writing the vertical and horizontal sum methods. Basically my code convert everything into 0 in the array b but does not keep the value from array a when the value is actually included in the sumToFind.

This is what I got by so far, thanks for help!:

```
public class FindTheSums {

    public static String arrayToString(int[][] a)
    {
        String arrayS = "";
        for(int r = 0; r<a.length; r++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c< a[r].length;c++)
            {
                arrayS+=a[r][c];
            }
            arrayS+= "\n";
        }
        return arrayS;
    }
    public static int[][] horizontalSums(int[][] a, int sumToFind)
    {
        int[][] b = new int[a.length][a[1].length];
        int hSum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<a.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j< a[i].length;j++)
            {
                hSum += a[i][j];
                if(hSum == sumToFind)
                {
                    b[i][j] = a[i][j];
                }
                else
                {
                    b[i][j] = 0;
                }

            }
        }
        return b;

    }
    public static int[][] verticalSums(int[][] a, int sumToFind)
    {
        int[][] b = new int[a.length][a[1].length];
        return b;
    }

}
```

Comment: Other than "please do my assignment for me", what is the question here?

Comment: I don't think this is the place for please-help-with-homework questions, but  try something like taking two elements ( Arr[constant][i] + Arr[constant][i + 1] == 20) and put it in a loop with the conditions. you can do this for either loop by switching the row and column index

Comment: My output is incorrect, basically it converts every thing into zero. I don't know how to set the if else statement in the for loop to include all of the integers that are counted in the wanted sum from array a and paste them into the new array(b).

Comment: @namsnath Thank you!!

Comment: @CherylLiang You're welcome! How about you edit the question and maybe format it a bit so its readable to include your problem?

Comment: @namsnath I just did it, thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < cols - 1; j++)
    {
        if(array[i][j] + array[i][j + 1] == sumToFind)
            //Do Something, since your question doesn't mention how you want
            //the data to be put in the new array
    }

}
```

If you want the data to be stored in an array of n x 2, you can just set `array2[i][0] = array[i][j]` and `array2[i][1] = array[i][j + 1]`

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it!!

Comment: Accepting the answer and/or upvoting is always a nice way to thank people ;)

Comment: Sorry for the unclear description. For adjacent value, I actually mean continuous. For example, if "7" is the wanted sum,  and "1, 2, 3, 1" show in the same column, these numbers would be print out.

Comment: that should be accomplished by adding another loop (might be better ways to do this, but I'm tired) and let it run till the sum exceeds 20 or you run out of elements and then place these elements in say a Stringbuffer so you can manipulate it and put it in an array when you need it